# How can I get the latest version of my nexus artifact into my jenkins batchscript?

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, build-process, nexus

I have this below line in a batch script in my Jenkins build job, which downloads a specific artifact from nexus server.

```
 call mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:get -DrepoUrl=http://10.101.2.23:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/ -Dartifact=test:update-service:1.0.3 -Ddest=Setups/Services/update-service.jar
```

Here I have hardcoded the latest version available at Nexus. Is it possible to get the latest version available at nexus using a jenkins variable? If so how? Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use "LATEST" for latest snapshot version or "RELEASE" for latest release version. In your case

```
call mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:get -DrepoUrl=http://10.101.2.23:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/ -Dartifact=test:update-service:RELEASE -Ddest=Setups/Services/update-service.jar
```

so you don't need a jenkins variable to inject a variable.

since you are using jenkins, my advice is to use the "Artifact Resolver"

hope this helps.

Comment: The "Release" keyword itself seems to be enough to download the latest release version. So I won't need the jenkins variable now right? Placing this exact command in the batch script would do. Why would I need the artifact resolveR?

Comment: "Artifact Resolver" does the same so you don't need a batch script in a clear way. this is why you using jenkins

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a global variable in Jenkins, go to `Manage Jenkins` > `Configure System` > `Global properties`. Check `Environment variables` and enter your key value pair. You can then use the global variable in your jobs with the syntax `$key` or `${key}`.

Comment: I got that part. But  how can I assign the value of that variable to be the latest release version in nexus?